# Measuring MySQL 'load' from query usage and query type frequency

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance

I have a mysql database with many tables.  This database powers a website which has been getting more and more traffic.

I've designed my database and queries to intentionally avoid joins that would create performance bottlenecks, and such so that I can split my tables onto separate servers as needed in the event specific tables have too much load (later on, I can shard individual tables as needed).

My question is this: given the number of tables I have, is there an easy way to detect which table and queries is receiving the most 'load': I'm specifically wondering about tables with high read-write usage.

I want some way to tell (aside from looking at my code and logs) to determine what tables ought to be moved to other servers to distribute requests and manage resources.  I'm using the term 'load' generally I know, and perhaps incorrectly(?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is precisely what the Percona Toolkit was made for (amongst many many other things). Specifically, `pt-query-digest`  ([Link](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html))- you can use it for a huge number of utilities, from slow queries to detecting SQL injection.

In this case `pt-query-digest` can be used along with the general strategy of setting your `long_query_time` to log all queries to the `slow_query_log` file by setting the `long_query_time` = 0. Now, ALL queries are logged to the slow query file (be sure to reset the time to prev value).

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.slow_query_log_file;
+------------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.slow_query_log_file             |
+------------------------------------------+
| /var/lib/ubuntu/mysql/slowquery.log            |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> SET GLOBAL slow_query_log_file='/tmp/sniffed_queries.log';
mysql> SET GLOBAL long_query_time = 0; 
mysql> FLUSH LOGS; #Clear the logs
```

So now you have a handy log of ALL QUERIES run on your server, without messing with your general log or another table, to analyze with pt-query-digest:

```
pt-query-digest /tmp/sniffed_queries.log
```

Will produce a great output that is extrement useful, of interest to you for starters:

3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24

```
# Profile
# Rank Query ID           Response time Calls R/Call Apdx V/M   Item
# ==== ================== ============= ===== ====== ==== ===== ==========
#    1 0x92F3B1B361FB0E5B  4.0522 50.0%   312 0.0130 1.00  0.00 SELECT wp_options
#    2 0xE71D28F50D128F0F  0.8312 10.3%  6412 0.0001 1.00  0.00 SELECT poller_output poller_item
#    3 0x211901BF2E1C351E  0.6811  8.4%  6416 0.0001 1.00  0.00 SELECT poller_time
#    4 0xA766EE8F7AB39063  0.2805  3.5%   149 0.0019 1.00  0.00 SELECT wp_terms wp_term_taxonomy wp_term_relationships
#    5 0xA3EEB63EFBA42E9B  0.1999  2.5%    51 0.0039 1.00  0.00 SELECT UNION wp_pp_daily_summary wp_pp_hourly_summary wp_pp_hits wp_posts
#    6 0x94350EA2AB8AAC34  0.1956  2.4%    89 0.0022 1.00  0.01 UPDATE wp_options
#    7 0x7AEDF19FDD3A33F1  0.1381  1.7%   909 0.0002 1.00  0.00 SELECT wp_options
#    8 0x4C16888631FD8EDB  0.1160  1.4%     5 0.0232 1.00  0.00 SELECT film
#    9 0xCFC0642B5BBD9AC7  0.0987  1.2%    50 0.0020 1.00  0.01 SELECT UNION wp_pp_daily_summary wp_pp_hourly_summary wp_pp_hits
#   10 0x88BA308B9C0EB583  0.0905  1.1%     4 0.0226 1.00  0.01 SELECT poller_item
#   11 0xD0A520C9DB2D6AC7  0.0850  1.0%   125 0.0007 1.00  0.00 SELECT wp_links wp_term_relationships wp_term_taxonomy
#   12 0x30DA85C940E0D491  0.0835  1.0%   542 0.0002 1.00  0.00 SELECT wp_posts
#   13 0x8A52FE35D340A347  0.0767  0.9%     4 0.0192 1.00  0.00 TRUNCATE TABLE poller_time
#   14 0x3E84BF7C0C2A3005  0.0624  0.8%   272 0.0002 1.00  0.00 SELECT wp_postmeta
#   15 0xA01053DA94ED829E  0.0567  0.7%   213 0.0003 1.00  0.00 SELECT data_template_rrd data_input_fields
#   16 0xBE797E1DD5E4222F  0.0524  0.6%    79 0.0007 1.00  0.00 SELECT wp_posts
#   17 0xF8EC4434E0061E89  0.0475  0.6%    62 0.0008 1.00  0.00 SELECT wp_terms wp_term_taxonomy
#   18 0xCDFFAD848B0C1D52  0.0465  0.6%     9 0.0052 1.00  0.01 SELECT wp_posts wp_term_relationships
#   19 0x5DE709416871BF99  0.0454  0.6%   260 0.0002 1.00  0.00 DELETE poller_output
#   20 0x428A588445FE580B  0.0449  0.6%   260 0.0002 1.00  0.00 INSERT poller_output
# MISC 0xMISC              0.8137 10.0%  3853 0.0002   NS   0.0 
<147 ITEMS>
```

From this example you can see that the R/Call for the SELECT...FROM wp_options call is causing the greatest load. There is a ton of great other info. **I would highly recommend getting to use the percona-toolkit early and often if you are going to stick with mysql** - I put them off for far, far too long and still kick myself for the headaches they would have prevented.

Percona has a great article on this, it is for their Percona Server MySQL build, which is excellent, but should still apply: [Identifying the load with the help of pt-query-digest and Percona Server](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/29/identifying-the-load-with-the-help-of-pt-query-digest-and-percona-server/)

Comment: I haven't tried your solution yet, but I looked into it and it seems like it will do what I want.  Answer accepted!

Comment: Wow! Seems like it is the best profile tool that I have ever seen and your detailed answer about how to use it is perfect! You make my day! Thanks!

Comment: In my case I also had to do `set global slow_query_log = 'ON'` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You could set triggers on the table and have the trigger insert the table name getting operated on to a separate tracking table.

I could see two ways of setting up such a trigger.
1. Have the trigger insert to the tracking table each time. Your tracking table would store the name of the table getting operated on. You could then tally up the number of updates by grouping the tracking table by table name. The problem here would be that each update would require a separate row.

1. Have the tracking table store both table name and count. Then have the trigger update the count as necessary:
   eg.
   SELECT * FROM trackingTable WHERE table_name = 'sometablename';
   IF @@ROWCOUNT == 0 -- sometablename is not already in the trackingTable
   BEGIN
     INSERT INTO sometablename VALUES('sometablename, 1); -- Insert into the table,count=1
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
    DECLARE @count AS INT;
    SET @count = (SELECT thecount FROM trackingTable WHERE table_name = 'sometablename');
    SET @count = @count+1; -- Increment the count by 1
    UPDATE trackingTable SET theCount=@count WHERE table_name='sometablename';
   END